# Restrict To date based on From date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to allow `To` date based on `from` date .If I choose `from date`as `24-04-2017` means, `To date` should allow dates from`24-04-2017` only.
 How can I do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 pastDaysdisable()
})
function pastDaysdisable() {
     var dtToday = new Date();
     var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
     var day = dtToday.getDate();
     var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
     if (month < 10)
         month = '0' + month.toString();
     if (day < 10)
         day = '0' + day.toString();

     var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
     $('#levFrom,#levTo').attr('min', maxDate);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="levFrom">
<input type="date" id="levTo">
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `type="date"`? I.e. firefox does not support additional html functionality for this input. I'd suggest you using external lib like datepicker mentioned below in our answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example with [jQuery datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Each time you change base date, we assign its value to `currentDate` variable and apply `minDate` property to our `#fromDate` datepicker.

Read my comments to have better understanding.

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#baseDate" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
    
    // if you set default date
    var currentDate = $( "#baseDate" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
    
    $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      minDate: currentDate
    });
    
    
    // If we change "fromDate"
    $( "#baseDate" ).change(function() {
      
      // get min date
      currentDate = $( "#baseDate" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
      // set min date
      $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", currentDate );
      console.log(currentDate);
    });
    
    
    

  } );
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 
<p>Date From: <input type="text" id="baseDate"></p>


<p>Min Date: <input type="text" id="fromDate"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind some event on your `from-date`. Either `blur` or `input` or `change` to capture the selected date from the `from-date`. Rest is exactly the same as you did there, just use the `value` of from-date for your Date object.

Note that the example below is Javascript (no jQuery). You can easily adapt it for jQuery if you really need to.

**Example:**

```js
var from = document.getElementById('levFrom'), 
    to = document.getElementById('levTo') 
;

from.addEventListener('change', limitDates);

function limitDates(e) {
  var fromDate = new Date(from.value), 
      minDate = []
  ;
  minDate[0] = fromDate.getFullYear();
  minDate[1] = (fromDate.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + (fromDate.getMonth() + 1) : (fromDate.getMonth() + 1);
  minDate[2] = fromDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + fromDate.getDate() : fromDate.getDate();
  to.setAttribute('min', minDate.join('-'));
 
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="levFrom">
<input type="date" id="levTo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi achieved this using jquery-ui datepicker().

```
$("#valid_from").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#valid_upto").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});

$("#valid_upto").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```

HTML Code :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Select from date" id="valid_from" name="valid_from">
<input type="text" placeholder="Select upto date" id="valid_upto" name="valid_upto">
```

Comment: No I don't want to use datepicker. I want to achieve it using `input type="date'`